# Why do Chinese characters turn into gibberish after it runs through compiler?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, visual-studio, unicode

So I am writing a program to turn a Chinese-English definition .txt file into a vocab trainer that runs through the CLI. However, in windows when I try to compile this in VS2017 it turns into gibberish and I'm not sure why. I think it was working OK in linux but windows seems to mess it up quite a bit. Does this have something to do with the encoding table in windows? Am I missing something? I wrote the code in Linux as well as the input file, but I tried writing the characters using windows IME and still has the same result. I think the picture speaks best for itself. Thanks

Note: Added sample of input/output as it appears in Windows, as requested. Also, input is UTF-8.

Sample of input

```
人(rén),person
刀(dāo),knife
力(lì),power
又(yòu),right hand; again
口(kǒu),mouth
```

Sample of output

```
Σ║║(r├⌐n),person
σêÇ(d─üo),knife
σè¢(l├¼),power
σÅê(y├▓u),right hand; again
σÅú(k╟Æu),mouth
σ£ƒ(t╟ö),earth
```

[Picture of Input file & Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JkTT.png)

Comment: Please post text, not pictures of text. What is your input file? UTF8?

Comment: Yes, the input is written in UTF-8. I didnt post text because I thought it would be too long and unclear versus a picture.

Comment: Iirc you have to set the font in the windows console to one that supports UTF-8 (Lucida if memory serves) also why not use `std::wcout`? See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49479764/2051159

Comment: Its already lucidia but I looked at your link and its more in depth than I was expecting lol. I will read up on it in the morning tomorrow and report back to see how it goes. Looks like you have to set up windows to work with these font types and locales... Linux seems to work more straight forward in this regard. Also, I tried wcout, but it didn't do anything. But I'll try some of the stuff they mention in the post you linked and see how it goes. Thanks again for the reference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17145109/c-file-character-encoding

Comment: @M.Ruiz Unicode, specifically UTF16 is the *default* string type for Windows since Windows NT 1.0. In the past this would be handled by wchar, wstring characters but in the last couple of C++ Standards the `char16_t` and `u16string_t` characters were introduced. *Linux* on the other hand doesn't deal with Unicode at all and depends on the environment's locale to be UTF8.  That's why in Windows code you'see multibyte or Unicode types but seldom on Linux.

Comment: @M.Ruiz How did you inspect the output? Those strings look like UTF8 bytes displayed using a single-byte codepage. Notice how `é` gets replaced by *two* characters, `├⌐`, exactly as it would on UTF8. `人` becomes *three* bytes, `Σ║║`. Could it be that the output is actually correct?

Comment: @M.Ruiz have you tried saving the output to a file and opening it with an editor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR: The Windows terminal hates Unicode. You can work around it, but it's not pretty.**

Your issues here are unrelated to "`char` versus `wchar_t`". In fact, there's nothing wrong with your program! The problems only arise when the text leaves through `cout` and arrives at the terminal.

---

You're probably used to thinking of a `char` as a "character"; this is a common (but understandable) misconception. In C/C++, the `char` type is usually synonymous with an **8-bit integer**, and thus is more accurately described as a **byte**.

Your text file **chineseVocab.txt** is encoded as UTF-8. When you read this file via `fstream`, what you get is a **string of UTF-8-encoded bytes**.

**There is no such thing as a "character" in I/O**; you're always transmitting **bytes** in a particular **encoding**. In your example, you are reading UTF-8-encoded bytes from a file handle (`fin`).

Try running this, and you should see identical results on both platforms (Windows and Linux):

```
int main()
{
    fstream fin("chineseVocab.txt");
    string line;
    while (getline(fin, line))
    {
        cout << "Number of bytes in the line: " << dec << line.length() << endl;
        cout << "    ";
        for (char c : line)
        {
            // Here we need to trick the compiler into displaying this "char" as an integer:
            unsigned int byte = (unsigned char)c;
            cout << hex << byte << "  ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here's what I see in mine (Windows):

```
Number of bytes in the line: 16
    e4  ba  ba  28  72  c3  a9  6e  29  2c  70  65  72  73  6f  6e

Number of bytes in the line: 15
    e5  88  80  28  64  c4  81  6f  29  2c  6b  6e  69  66  65

Number of bytes in the line: 14
    e5  8a  9b  28  6c  c3  ac  29  2c  70  6f  77  65  72

Number of bytes in the line: 27
    e5  8f  88  28  79  c3  b2  75  29  2c  72  69  67  68  74  20  68  61  6e  64  3b  20  61  67  61  69  6e

Number of bytes in the line: 15
    e5  8f  a3  28  6b  c7  92  75  29  2c  6d  6f  75  74  68
```

So far, so good.

---

The problem starts now: you want to write those same UTF-8-encoded bytes to another file handle (`cout`).

The `cout` file handle is connected to your CLI (the "terminal", the "console", the "shell", whatever you wanna call it). The CLI reads bytes from `cout` and **decodes** them into characters so they can be displayed.

- Linux terminals are usually configured to use a **UTF-8 decoder**. Good news! **Your bytes are UTF-8-encoded**, so your Linux terminal's decoder **matches** the text file's encoding. That's why everything looks good in the terminal.
- Windows terminals, on the other hand, are usually configured to use a **system-dependent decoder** (yours appears to be [**DOS codepage 437**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)). Bad news! **Your bytes are UTF-8-encoded**, so your Windows terminal's decoder **does not match** the text file's encoding. That's why everything looks garbled in the terminal.

---

**OK, so how do you solve this?** Unfortunately, I couldn't find any portable way to do it... You will need to fork your program into a Linux version and a Windows version. In the Windows version:

1. Convert your UTF-8 bytes into UTF-16 code units.
2. Set standard output to UTF-16 mode.
3. Write to `wcout` instead of `cout`
4. Tell your users to change their terminals to a font that supports Chinese characters.

Here's the code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <windows.h>

#include <fcntl.h>  
#include <io.h>  
#include <stdio.h> 

using namespace std;

// Based on this article:
// https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/mt763237?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
wstring utf16FromUtf8(const string & utf8)
{
    std::wstring utf16;

    // Empty input --> empty output
    if (utf8.length() == 0)
        return utf16;

    // Reject the string if its bytes do not constitute valid UTF-8
    constexpr DWORD kFlags = MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS;

    // Compute how many 16-bit code units are needed to store this string:
    const int nCodeUnits = ::MultiByteToWideChar(
        CP_UTF8,       // Source string is in UTF-8
        kFlags,        // Conversion flags
        utf8.data(),   // Source UTF-8 string pointer
        utf8.length(), // Length of the source UTF-8 string, in bytes
        nullptr,       // Unused - no conversion done in this step
        0              // Request size of destination buffer, in wchar_ts
    );

    // Invalid UTF-8 detected? Return empty string:
    if (!nCodeUnits)
        return utf16;

    // Allocate space for the UTF-16 code units:
    utf16.resize(nCodeUnits);

    // Convert from UTF-8 to UTF-16
    int result = ::MultiByteToWideChar(
        CP_UTF8,       // Source string is in UTF-8
        kFlags,        // Conversion flags
        utf8.data(),   // Source UTF-8 string pointer
        utf8.length(), // Length of source UTF-8 string, in bytes
        &utf16[0],     // Pointer to destination buffer
        nCodeUnits     // Size of destination buffer, in code units          
    );

    return utf16;
}

int main()
{
    // Based on this article:
    // https://blogs.msmvps.com/gdicanio/2017/08/22/printing-utf-8-text-to-the-windows-console/
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);

    fstream fin("chineseVocab.txt");
    string line;
    while (getline(fin, line))
        wcout << utf16FromUtf8(line) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In my terminal, it mostly looks OK after I change the font to **MS Gothic**:

[image: Most Chinese characters look OK]

Some characters are still messed up, but that's due to the font not supporting them.

Comment: To clarifiy this (good) answer, I would state that _your program is not the problem_. The problem is the _terminal which is displaying the output of your program_. If you were to write to a file instead of standard output, then open that file in a UTF-8-aware text editor, you should see the correct output. That knowledge may help you determine what lengths you need to go to to "fix" this.